# Is there a workaround for the negative balance bug in GTA 5?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

After completing a certain mission with Franklin where he pays 50 $ to someone my balance is negative. Receiving payments from selling stocks and completing taxi missions is not added to the balance so it's stuck. This is an issue known and listed at the [Rockstar's support site.](http://support.rockstargames.com/hc/en-us/articles/200299226-Being-stuck-with-negative-money-as-Franklin-in-GTA-V) Was someone able to figure out a workaround? I don't want to progress in the story until Franklin can receive money again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just found a way to fix it: Collect the money left on the ground by dead persons. This money is added to your balance.

Comment: Thanks a million! I'd kiss you if StackExchange hadn't made me sign that form saying I wouldn't!

Answer (score 1):

This bug is fixed on October 1 update, in both Xbox 360 & PS3 .

Reference: http://www.rockstargames.com/newswire/article/51500/gtav-title-update-details.html